# Font is visible which is not used by us

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to know that why website is showing "Ubuntu" font in mobile chrome & firefox browser (updated version) while Ubuntu font is not used by us, But we are using only Open Sans & Lora which is showing perfectly on other browsers such as opera, uc, default browser.

Demo:- http://www.slondeals.com please check the font between Posts boxes are looks like "Ubuntu" and it should be Open Sans

Here is CSS file with fonts:- http://www.slondeals.com/wp-content/themes/eleven40-custom/style.css

Answer (score 1):

You have in your CSS some :

```
font-family: sans-serif;
font-family: monospace, serif;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; // This one for buttons for example
```

So you are not using only `Open Sans` ans `Lora`. The system also use the default fonts when you specify `sans-serif`, `monospace`, `serif` or `Oswald`, wich may looks like `Ubuntu` font.

If you want `Open Sans` instead, replace the corresponding occurences by:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif
```

Comment: @YashveerArya Replace in your CSS `font-family: XXXX` by `font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif`. If you don't know how to change a font in CSS, you should learn CSS..